# Evolution and thunderbird sharing same mail data?

Tags: evolution, email, thunderbird

I have been using Evolution for a quite long and it has downloaded around 1.6GBs of mails from gmail. I want to try thunderbird but I dont want to re download everything again. Is that possible to have both clients sharing same data? I'll make sure I don't use both at the same time if that matters. I'll move to thunderbird fully if I'm happy with it.

Problems I face with evolution is that I have to have the GUI running always if I want to get instant alerts and send mail immediately. Also it loads the messages slow and even after I move to the next mail, it slowly downloads all the linked images before moving on.

Comment: why not set up your GMail as IMAP?

Comment: @Tatkkat. I want the mails available offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will tip them over pretty good one to use a mail client like Thunderbird and Evolution. Let's see how to **minimize a program to "system tray"** (the area of icons on the panel where the clock) when we close the application.

In this way we will not always open the window or the bar will take place in open windows and only appear when you click on the icon in question.

We are going to install a small application that gives this functionality to the client even without support for it. It's called "alltray" and you can install it using Synaptic or console:

> sudo aptitude install alltray

We have only done this to create a launcher and if you want you can add it to your kiba-dock, AWN or login (System> Preferences> Sessions> Startup Programs.)

The command that you must add the following to Thunderbird and Evolution, respectively:

```
alltray "thunderbird --component = mail"
alltray "evolution --component = mail"
```

Will observe the icon done in the commentary. To show you just have to click on this icon and if you want to minimize it again by pressing the button to close the window frame (do not use File> Exit).

**sharing same mail data ?** [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=346982)

Comment: Thanks. Hope thunderbird alerts if I receive a new mail.